# Riemann zeta function at negative integers as combination of Stirling numbers and Gregory coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, riemann-zeta, stirling-numbers

Calculating the regularized sum

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{k}$$

in two different ways gives the following relation:

$$\zeta(-k)=(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\ell!S_{2}(k,\ell)G_{\ell+1}$$

where $S_{2}(k,\ell)$ are Stirling numbers of second kind and $G_{\ell}$ are the Gregory coefficients,

$$\frac{z}{\text{log}(1+z)}=\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}G_{\ell}z^{\ell}$$

Is there a proof of this relation?